# Required request part 'file' is not present but the settings may be right

Tags: java

**interface**:

```
OssInnerUploadResponse upload4Back(@RequestPart(value = "file") @NotNull MultipartFile file, @RequestParam(value = "appCode") AppCodeEnum appCode);
```

**controller**:

```
OssInnerUploadResponse upload4Back(@RequestPart(value = "file") MultipartFile file, @RequestParam(value = "appCode") AppCodeEnum appCode){
}
```

**Invoke**:

```
DefaultMultipartFile file = new DefaultMultipartFile(fileName, outputStream.toByteArray());
OssInnerUploadResponse result = commonOssFeignClient.upload4Back(file, appCode);
```

Comment: Required request part 'file' is not present   but why???

Answer (score 0):

Use `@RequestParam` instead of `@RequestPart` to receive MultipartFile. It will work.

```
OssInnerUploadResponse upload4Back(@RequestParam(value = "file") MultipartFile file, @RequestParam(value = "appCode") AppCodeEnum appCode){
}
```

Comment: Hi, How would you send the file in the endpoint's URL in case of using @RequestParam?